# What does double parentheses mean in a require

Tags: node.js, express

I know what this require statement does.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

But sometimes i have seen two parentheses after the require.

```
var routes = require('./routes')(app);
```

**Q)** What does this mean, and how does it work?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23982490/2600208) may help

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is a pattern in which the [`module.exports`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) of the module you are requiring is set to a function. [Requiring](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_require_id) that module returns a function, and the parentheses after the require evaluates the function with an argument.

In your example above, your `./routes/index.js` file would look something like the following:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  });
  // ...
};
```

This pattern is often used to pass variables to modules, as can bee seen above with the `app` variable.

Comment: Aaah.... So this means that this:
`var express = require('express');
var app = express();`
**could** be written like this: 
`var app = require('express')();`
...even if this not implies that it **should** be =)

Answer (score 14):

Well, [require](http://www.nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require) is a function provided by Node.js that basically loads a module for you and it returns whatever you expose in the module that you loaded.

If what you expose (through the use of module.exports) in a given module is a function, then that is what requires returns. For instance.

```
//moduleX.js
module.exports = function(){
  return "Helo World";
}
```

Then if you require it, you get a function back

```
var f = require('./moduleX');
console.log(f()); //hello world
```

Of course, you could invoke the function directly once you require it.

```
var greet = require('./moduleX')();
console.log(greet);
```

Answer (score 2):

That mean that behind that, there is a function that is exported using `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
   app.get("/", function(req, res){});
}
```

See also http://www.choskim.me/understanding-module-exports-and-exports-in-node-js/

Sidenote:

You could create function on the fly:

A.js

```
module.exports = function(data) {
   return function(req, res, next) {
        // Do something with data
        next();

}
```

main.js

```
...
app.use(require("A")(data));
...
```