# module.exports TypeError and has no method

Tags: node.js

t1.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    return new obj(app);
};

var obj = function(app) {
    this.app = app;

};

obj.prototype.query = function() {


    return "ok";
};
```

t2.js

```
var a = require('./t1.js');

console.log(a.query());
```

execute node t2.js

it reports

```
console.log(a.query());
                  ^
TypeError: Object function (app) {
    return new obj(app);
} has no method 'query'
```

your comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `require('./t1.js')` returns a function that you export.

Here is the solution:

```
var a = require('./t1.js')();
/* or...
var myApp = {};
var a = require('./t1.js')(myApp);
*/
console.log(a.query());  //now it's "ok"
```

Comment: but require('./t1.js')() is quite strange, never seen before

Comment: Yeah, this is a JavaScript magic :) Take a look at [my answer about double parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23982490/2600208)